A removed and tiled over GFCI outlet location
A GFCI outlet was removed and covered over with tile in the kitchen and is hard to find. There are several other regular outlets but no other GFCI outlets. Can one of the regular outlet be replaced with a GFCI outlet?

Your situation isn't clear. What does "removed and covered over with tile in the kitchen and is hard to find" mean? Was it eliminated? Buried? "Hard to find" implies that it's still somehow installed and accessible. Please revise to clarify. Also take the [tour].

"is hard to find". If it was removed, no one is ever going to find it. How is its removal relevant to the question?

The current Title "A removed and tiled over GFCI outlet location" isn't a question. And if it were, it would be different from the question in the Body. They need to be the same question.

Was the box removed, or is it now a buried box with wire splices?

-1 for lack of details. See comments.

Any "regular outlet", i.e. duplex receptacle, can be replaced with a GFCI outlet.


covered over with tile

Another answer already covers (pun intended) the problem with removing a receptacle (you need to have both a minimum number of circuits in the kitchen and receptacles at particular locations/maximum distance between them) and GFCI protection.
But there is another issue: Junction boxes must always remain accessible. Even if a receptacle is removed from a box and replaced with a blank cover, if there are still live wires in the box then the box must be accessible. That means you must be able to get to that box without any special tools or destroying anything. The screws holding the cover on are fine, but that's about it. So if the box was actually covered with tile, as opposed to that being a shortcut for "the receptacle was removed, the wires disconnected at their source so that there are no live wires and then the box was covered with tile" then you have a code violation that must be resolved. Any live wires inside a box could someday be a fire hazard, and behind tile you wouldn't know about the problem until it was way too late.

Code Compliance
Under most circumstances, removing any countertop receptacle would violate NEC 210.52(C).  That means replacing some other receptacle besides the one that's missing would not bring this kitchen up to code.
Also, NEC paragraphs 210.8 and 210.52(B) combine to require a minimum of 2 GFCI devices for the kitchen countertop.  The exceptions would be for a 2-pole circuit breaker, or for much older dwellings that only have one circuit for the countertop.  The fact that one was removed leaving zero GFCIs raises some questions about this.
GFCI Protection
If the GFI is simply missing, its location is not as important as a specific outlet.  For example, it's possible to use a GFI circuit breaker, or any receptacle that is between the countertop and the circuit breaker.  So yes, it is possible to add GFI protection at another location that will protect "several other outlets".
